# How does the flag window trigger?

Tags: javascript, html

Question related to the flag(report-post) window on stackoverflow - How does it trigger?

I get this:

```
<td class="vt">
  <div class="post-menu">
    <a href="/q/7444908/81800" title="short permalink to this question" id="link-post-7444908">link</a>
    <span class="lsep">|</span>
    <a href="/posts/7444908/edit" class="edit-post" title="revise and improve this post">edit</a>
    <span class="lsep">|</span>
    <a id="flag-post-7444908" href="#" title="flag this post for serious problems or moderator attention">flag</a>
  </div>

</td>
```

I don't understand how it opens up. Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 3):

Stackoverflow uses [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/behavioralseparation) to attach the onclick handler that opens up a layer that acts like a modal dialog. They do not use jQuery UI for the dialog, but you can see a same idea with [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).